# Error when launching WPF clickonce application from network share

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

We have a WPF application published to a network share using clickonce. The application is only available online. After windows update KB4515842 on the client computers we started experiencing problems as described below. No changes has been made to the application.

When I start the application using IE it is downloaded and started correctly. There are however some parts of the application that doesn't work as before. We have a listview with templates for different types of items. When an item is selected, additional information is shown in an area using a template depending on the selected type of the item in the listview. The templates are selected using a DataTemplateSelector with the selected item in the listview as input. The DataTemplateSelector is not triggered after the update, hence no information is shown for the selected item.

The application uses .Net 4.5.2. Problem occurs on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

The problem only occurs when the application is started through the network share. No problem in Visual studio or when starting the clickonce installed application from ..\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0...

It also works when I deploy the application as available offline (start menu items created etc.)

Uninstalling the update also resolves the problem. On Windows 7 I uninstalled KB4519568, on Windows 10 KB4524098 (which both include KB4515842).

Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for our problem so I am posting the solution if anybody encounters the same problem.

The Selected item in the listview had a binding to a property in our viewmodel. The property in the viewmodel looked similar to this:

```
public Shared.Task SelectedTask
{
   get
   {
      return _selectedTask;
   }
   private set
   {
      _selectedTask = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedTask);
   }
}
```

I am uncertain how this could work with a private access modifier on the set part of the property, but it has worked previously and still works in Visual Studio 2017 and when running the installed version of the clickonce application. Anyway when I made the set public it also works for our network deployed clickonce application (The PropertyChanged event is fired for SelectedTask and the DataTemplateSelector which listens to changes of SelectedTask returns a new DataTemplate).